# html canvas shadow/blur won't go away

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

There is a shadow on the bottom and right sides of a rectangle I've drawn in the canvas on the upper-left hand corner of my window here:
**http://thomasshouler.com/datavis/gugg/ratio.html**

I haven't set any positive values to the relevant context attributes `(shadowBlur, shadowOffsetY, etc.)`, so what gives?

Canvas code snippet:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.shadowBlur=0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY=0;
var width = 50;
var height = 4;
var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,width,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,'#008000');
grd.addColorStop(0.5,'#CCCCCC');
grd.addColorStop(1,'#FF0000');
ctx.fillStyle=grd;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
```

Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think there is issue with the gradient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to scaling as the canvas is displayed. Your original fragment with a very small gradient and scaled up http://jsfiddle.net/CBzu4/ clearly shows the blurred outline.

Drawing larger (making sure there is no css scaling) it looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/CBzu4/1/ and the code is the same as yours, just rearranged:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var width = 50 * 8;
var height = 4 * 8;

var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,width,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,'#008000');
grd.addColorStop(0.5,'#FFFF00');
grd.addColorStop(1,'#FF0000');

ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(5,5,width,height);
```

Same code, but this time the canvas scaled up with the embedded style: http://jsfiddle.net/CBzu4/2/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 120%; height: 120%;" width="600" height="80">
```

The final version is again the same as yours, no css scaling at all and no blurred outline: http://jsfiddle.net/CBzu4/3/